# How to get deleted files back with git pull?

Tags: git, backup

I had up to date repository. Then I had deleted several files and this was mistake. I would like to get fresh repository back. I do

```
$ git pull origin master
```

And expect to get everything from server, but getting message that everything is up to date.

How to get my sources from server using `git pull` then?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can reset local branch to what's at remote

```
git reset --hard origin/main
```

Comment: Because the user doesn't say anywhere that he commited the changes to the project. He could just checkout the files that he deleted...

Comment: @NativeCoder it doesn't matter if he committed them or not, a hard reset to the remote tracking branch will restore the working directory to that state. Specifically, he states *"I would like to get fresh repository back."*

Comment: Upon second look, the op DOES state "with git pull". In which case this would be the only "correct" answer. Sorry! Have that rep back!

Comment: Be careful while doing HARD reset. It will reset everything including your configurations.

Comment: prefered method: git checkout [dir_name]

Comment: it is git reset --hard origin/main

Comment:  Please people stop upvoting this answer. See Harald's answer and Jeff Puckett's amazing comment ! SO is such a failure here.

Answer (score 42):

The files are in your local git history so you won't need to pull code to get them back. Run

```
git checkout <file>
```

on the missing files. If you don't have any uncommited changes then

```
git checkout .
```

in the git root directory will work as well.

Comment: This is my favorite answer, despite mine having been accepted with ~3x more upvotes. Cheers 

Answer (score 16):

This shows all the deleted files.

```
git ls-files --deleted
```

This will restore the deleted file.

```
git checkout <deleted file name with complete path>
```

Answer (score 4):

For all the unstaged files use

`git checkout -- .`

Or the more safer way

`git clean -fd`

Comment: Assuming he didn't commit anything

Comment: This does delete any modified files. It does not just do a fresh pull of deleted files (even if OP wants a fresh restore...good to mention since it is easy for others to miss that point)

Answer (score 3):

thats all you need

```
git reset --hard
git fetch origin 
git pull origin master
```

Comment: No need to fetch on origin if you will pull next

Answer (score 1):

What is the result of `git status` command ?
You can also try `git reset --hard origin/master`

Answer (score 1):

This will restore all of the deleted files since they still reside in your local repository.

```
git checkout -- .
```

Whenever I want to start over with a file I messed up, or even just scrap the in repository builds, I just delete everything except the .git folder and run this to get back to a fresh start.

Answer (score 0):

If you just revert your change, you will get all the files deleted. It is not a workaround (that you mentioned) where you have to reset, IMO it is better than getting fresh repo.

Answer (score 0):

To get the deleted files from git pull, we can use this command to retrieve this deleted files back

```
git rev-list -n 1 HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

try the command

```
$ git reflog
```

above command will give you tips of branches and other references that were updated in the local repository like below (Recent updates are at top)

```
da82426 (HEAD -> main) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD
da82426 (HEAD -> main) HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to HEAD~
774b952 (origin/master, origin/main) HEAD@{2}: reset: moving to HEAD
774b952 (origin/master, origin/main) HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from master to main
8851ece (master) HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from master to master
8851ece (master) HEAD@{5}: commit: First commit
8bd9080 HEAD@{6}: commit (initial): Initialize project using Create React App
```

Then revert to your desired stage by using command like below

```
$ git reset --hard 8851ece
```

It will probably get files back.

Answer (score -1):

What about git stash command ? 
If you didn't commit your changes (e.g the files deletions) then you can just run `git stash`

Comment: `git stash` won't help here. Just take the accepted answer as accepted